# Provision Azure Kubernetes ACS cluster using Azure 2.0 CLI

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-cli, windows-container

I'm trying to provision an Azure ACS Kubernetes cluster using Windows nodes.  The Azure 2.0 CLI worked fine creating a Linux cluster, but it failed when creating a Windows cluster.

Here is the command I executed:

```
***@DAVEPC:~$ az acs create -n RMA-KB-01 -d rmakb -g RG-KB-01 --generate-ssh-keys --orchestrator-type kubernetes --windows --admin-password=*****
```

This is the error:

```
At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. {   "status": "Failed",   "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "ProvisioningFailed",
        "message": "Provisioning of resource(s) for container service 'RMA-KB-01' in resource group 'RG-KB-01' failed with errors: Resource type: Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines, name: 1E4FCacs9001, id: /subscriptions/64b38e64-5dbd-438d-84d3-94e87b553a51/resourceGroups/RG-KB-01/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/1E4FCacs9001, StatusCode: NotFound, StatusMessage: \\n {\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ImageNotFound\",\r\n    \"target\": \"imageReference\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The platform image 'MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2016-Datacenter-with-Containers:2016.0.20170127' is not available. Verify that all fields in the storage profile are correct.\"\r\n  }\r\n}\r\nResource type: Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines, name: 1E4FCacs9000, id: /subscriptions/64b38e64-5dbd-438d-84d3-94e87b553a51/resourceGroups/RG-KB-01/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/1E4FCacs9000, StatusCode: NotFound, StatusMessage: \\n {\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ImageNotFound\",\r\n    \"target\": \"imageReference\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The platform image 'MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2016-Datacenter-with-Containers:2016.0.20170127' is not available. Verify that all fields in the storage profile are correct.\"\r\n  }\r\n}\r\nResource type: Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines, name: 1E4FCacs9002, id: /subscriptions/64b38e64-5dbd-438d-84d3-94e87b553a51/resourceGroups/RG-KB-01/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/1E4FCacs9002, StatusCode: NotFound, StatusMessage: \\n {\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ImageNotFound\",\r\n    \"target\": \"imageReference\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The platform image 'MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2016-Datacenter-with-Containers:2016.0.20170127' is not available. Verify that all fields in the storage profile are correct.\"\r\n  }\r\n}\r\n"
      }
    ]   } }  Correlation ID: c69bc7a4-2d0a-431b-ac7e-f98894110eea
```

I've just also tried this process using the Azure Portal and got the same error.  Is the Windows Container Kubernetes preview bugged?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that its a bug, there is no such VM Image:

```
C:\> Get-AzureRmVMImage -Location westeurope -PublisherName $pubName -Offer $offerName `
      -Skus 2016-Datacenter-with-Containers | select version

Version
-------
2016.127.20170406
2016.127.20170411
2016.127.20170510
```

I've reproduced your error.
You should raise an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20kubernetes).

Comment: Issue created, though I don't think it's specific to the CLI: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/3594

Comment: I'm running into the same problem in eastus.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but I think you should use az a**k**s instead of az acs. Nice blog about it [here](https://medium.com/bitnami-perspectives/az-aci-aks-acs-in-5-minutes-top-chrono-65c9952dfeb8).

ACS is [pretty deprecated](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-container-service-will-retire-on-january-31-2020/) service (it was Azure offering for multi-containers orchestrators), and now it replaced by AKS.